# How to generate a unique id?

Tags: anchor, rust

I have a struct which I want to store on the blockchain:

```
pub struct Item {
  pub id: String,
  pub link: String,
  pub user_address: Pubkey,
}
```

Now I want to generate an id for it in the Solana program. If I [add the UUID package](https://docs.rs/uuid/latest/uuid/) and try to call `Uuid::new_v4()`, I get the following error.

> error: target is not supported, for more information see:
> https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets

**Question**: How to generated a UUID in a Solana program? Or alternatively, how to generate a unique identifier of any sort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without much context, your best bet may be to use a public key as the id?

```
let id = Keypair::new().pubkey();
```

---

Though I can imagine that the `Item` struct is stored in an account. So that accounts' address can already act as the unique id.

Comment: using the account's address as the `id` is The Way :tm: